# Filter Seq[Map[k,v]] given a Seq[String]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter, maps

I have this `Seq[Map[String, String]]` :

```
     val val1 = Seq(
          Map("Name" -> "Heidi", 
             "City" -> "Paris", 
             "Age" -> "23"), 
          Map(("Country" -> "France")), 
          Map("Color" -> "Blue", 
             "City" -> "Paris"))
```

and I have this Seq[String]

```
  val val2 = Seq["Name", "Country", "City", "Department"]
```

Expected output is val1 with all keys present in val2 (I want to filter out the (k,v) from v1 that have keys that are not present in val2) :

**`val expected = Seq(Map("Name" -> "Heidi", "City" -> "Paris"), Map( "Country" -> "France")), Map("City" -> "Paris"))`**

*Age* and *Color* are strings that are not in val2, I want to omit them from val1 map.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what you propose is a right approach but nevertheless, it can be done like this:

```scala
val1.map(_.filter {
    case (key, value) => val2.contains(key)
})
```

Comment: worked with   val1.map(_.filter { map = val2.contains(map._1) }

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want something like this:
*(note that I used a `Set` instead of a `List` to make `contains` faster)*

```scala
def ensureMapsHaveOnlyValidKeys[K, V](validKeys: Set[K])(data: IterableOnce[Map[K, V]]): List[Map[K, V]] =
  data
    .iterator
    .filter(_.keysIterator.forall(validKeys.contains))
    .toList
```